# Scheduled task running batch but not exe within the batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I know there are similar questions already out there, but none of the other solutions seem to help.

Using Windows 7, I have an executable (for this explanation, I am calling it test.exe) that takes a parameter of the current date.

Example when using the run command:

`c:\test.exe 12/26/2014`

The executable needs to be ran on a daily schedule.

I have the following batch file set up to run the exe with the required parameters:

```
@echo off
::This batch will be ran daily to start the exe program
set dateFormat=%DATE:~4,2%/%DATE:~7,2%/%DATE:~10,4%
echo Batch started %dateFormat% %Time%>> BatchLogfile.txt
set testfile=C:\test.exe
start %testfile% %dateFormat%
pause
```

I can run the batch successfully by double-clicking on it in explorer, but when I add it as a scheduled task it does not actually start the exe.

The batch does run and I can see the processes for the cmd and the exe, but the exe "interface" does not pop up. The echo line in the batch writes out to the log file successfully.

On the scheduled task, I am currently using `cmd` for the program/script and the following params:

```
/k "C:\test.bat"
```

I have also tried the following arguments unsuccessfully in the task scheduler:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

/c start "" "C:\test.bat"

/k start "C:\test.bat"
```

Is there anything else I should try so that the exe "interface" shows on the screen? Perhaps there is a better way to run the exe other than task scheduler?

Comment: Note that the format of `%DATE%` depends on the user's internationalization settings, so that code will only work as-is in the United States (and only if the user hasn't chosen a different format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the GUI for test.exe, then you will need to configure the respective Windows Scheduled Task to "Run only when user is logged on". Of course then the process would only run for the configured user account.

This is available to select in the Security Options section in the General tab of the respective scheduled task.

Comment: Ah, yep. I was over-thinking this. I remote into the computer that the task is on and I thought that the user logged off when I closed the remote session. Thanks Jason.